# Allocating array (list) algorithm permutations in python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, python-itertools

So i'm having trouble to solve the following problem:

given an array size, lets say for the ease of the question size =20

it is filled with zeros as follows
arr = [0]*20   ==> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

we have couple of constant sample sizes, such as 4,3,2

SampleA=4, SampleB=3, SampleC= 2

i need to have the permutations/variations of how to **allocate** the list.

i can put each sample in different **place/index**

for example, sampleA= 4 i can put it in indexes of 0:3, or 1:4... 15:19..
(as you can see, there are quite a lot of possibilities)

the thing gets complicated once it get more crowded, for example:

3+2+3 +4

[0, x, x, x, 0, 0, x x, 0, x, x, x, 0, 0, 0, 0, x, x,x, x]

what i basically need, is to find **all** the possibilities to allocate samples,

i get a dictionary:
key = sample size of indexes, and the 
value=many times it repeats.

for the upper example: {3:2,2:1,4:1}

and i would like the function to return a list of **indexes** !=0

for this example:
[0, x, x, x, 0, 0, x x, 0, x, x, x, 0, 0, 0, 0, x, x,x, x]

the function will return:
list_ind = [0,5,6,9,13,14,15,16]

Comment: Check your example - it is very strange... Is it allowed to set two samples together without separating 0? Show your attempts until massive downvoting.

Comment: i've added a solution.
basically, you can have samples together, for example:
[0,0,0,x,x,x,x,y,y,y,y,0,0,0,z,z,z,0,w,w,w,w,0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i asked a colleague to help, and we came into a solution:

i put an example of:
 4:2, 3:1, 2:1

or verbally:

two times 4, one time 3, one time 2
the code below:

*if someone can optimize, will be great

```
size_of_wagon = 20
dct = {4:2,3:1,2:1}
l = [item for sublist in [[k] * v for (k, v) in dct.items()] for item in sublist]


def gen_func(lstOfSamples, length, shift):
    try:
        # print(f'lstOfSamples={lstOfSamples}')
        sample = lstOfSamples[0]  # Take first sample
        for i in range(length - sample):
            for x in gen_func(lstOfSamples[1:], length - (sample + i), shift + sample + i):
                yield [(shift + i, sample)] + x
    except:
        yield []


g = list(gen_func(l, size_of_wagon, 0))

for i in g:
    print(i)
print(len(g))
```